# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.3:run (default-cli)

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-boot, maven

Les comento, estoy desarrollando un proyecto en netbeans 8.2 con java y spring (soy nuevo en esto), lo inicié con start.spring.io. Miren, este error aparece cuando le doy run a mi proyecto.

---

> Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.3:run
> (default-cli) on project almacendemo: Application finished with exit
> code: 1 -> [Help 1]

---

Para solucionar este error, leí en un foro que se debe ejecutar en la terminal mvn clean install, pero luego de hacerlo me aparecía el siguiente error (el cual tampoco pude solucionar):

> failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test
> (default-test) there are test failures

La verdad no sé a que se deben los errores, creo que es un problema de versiones de maven.

Les comparto más detalles del proyecto así me ayudan.

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.matias</groupId>
    <artifactId>almacendemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>almacendemo</name>
    <description>Demo de proyecto sistema de ventas para almacen</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>     
        </plugins>
    </build> 

</project>
```

**APPLICATION.PROPERTIES**

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/almacen?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username: root
spring.datasource.password: root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false
```

**MAVEN VERSION**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MAVEN INSTALADO EN NETBEANS**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**VARIABLES DE ENTORNO**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**JDK**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Espero sus respuestas. Desde ya, muchas gracias!*

Comment: El mensaje `there are test failures` indica que tenes classes en la carpeta de test packages que contienen tests y están fallando. Deberías ver de arreglarlos

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, ahora intento lo que dices y te comento.

Comment: Solucioné el problema del error en el test pegando `<plugin>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>     <version>2.19.1</version>     <dependencies>         <dependency>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>             <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>             <version>2.19.1</version>         </dependency>     </dependencies> </plugin>`

 en el POM. Como muestra aquí [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817329/spring-boot-package-to-war-tests-fail) 
**El otro error sigue apareciendo**